# How to test Django JSON-ified ISO8601 Datetime

Tags: django

I'm testing with AjaxResponse with my request factory on a datetime. The problem is the string that Django gives is like this: `2020-08-27T22:46:07.354Z`

But when I have datetime object, and I use the isoformat() method, I don't get the same string: `2020-08-27T22:46:07.354734+00:00`

How am I going to be able to assert? I'm looking to assert by comparing the JSON with my own Python list (The list is what I can customize).

Comment: Is there maybe a specific function??? Maybe json.dumps?

Comment: There's gotta be some kind of default internal function that I can just take advantage of...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bast in Discord.py; the datetime conversion is not even iso8601 entirely... it's defined by ECMA-262 which is for JS:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

DjangoJSONEncoder().default(datetime_obj)
>>> '2020-08-28T03:41:59.194Z'
```

whereas using the `.isoformat()` method from standard lib would return 6 rather than 3 decimal points and use +00:00 rather than Z.